# Is it a good practice to initialize a variable if its use depends on a decider

Tags: c++

Suppose the following code where we have a structure with variables and a second structure where we have a function where we initialize the vectors

```
int decider1 = //userinput;
int decider2 = //userinput;
struct randomStruct
{
    std::vector<double> foo;
    std::vector<double> foo2;
    std::vector<double> foo3;
};

struct randomStruct2
{ 
   randomStruct foo4;
   void setupArray();
};
```

Now we have a global variables where it would only be used only if the user decides so

```
void randomStruct2::setupArray() 
{     
      foo4.foo.resize(1);
      foo4.foo2.resize(1);
      if(decider1 && decider2)
      {
         foo4.foo.resize(1);
      }
}
```

I faced some crashes where another developer tried to assign the variable value just depending on lets say `decider1` and it was of course an empty vector.

Now my question is from development point of view is it a good practice to just initialize the vector regardless of the user decision to avoid further crashes in the future or I apply a check at every point in other .cpp files where I should check for both the deciders before being assigned?

Comment: Getting an immediate error when you write a mistake (and thus a bug) is a good thing in my book. Crashes are your friends. No one wants an application that tries to survive a fatal error and finally dies somewhere down the road when it's too late to get any information as to what went wrong.

Comment: White the variables are not used in this case, later in the application development you may forget that and use them accidentally.

Comment: Use of static variables for (almost) *anything* is often considered bad practice.   Separating creation of an object from initialisation is ALSO often considered bad practice -  better to wait until all needed information is available, and THEN construct the object by passing that information to an appropriate constructor.   The constructor, regardless of what information it receives, should set things up so the object can be used appropriately (i.e. set up appropriately preconditions that all public member functions can safely assume are true).